# AutoLayout + heightForRowAtIndexPath/sizeWithFont not working correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I've got a custom cell with the following AutoLayout:

```
    NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[descriptionLabel]-35-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[descriptionLabel]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
```

In my tableViewDelegate, the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is calculated like this:

```
return [cell.descriptionLabel systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 20;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when my text wraps - it's only correct for cells with text where no wrapping is happening. What am I missing?

Comment: did you try UILayoutFittingExpandedSize ?

Comment: yes, doesn't change anything; it only works if I set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth, but I don't like to set it to a static number...

Answer (score 2):

When I first faced this issue in iOS7 I've tried all possible ways to correctly estimate size of a wrapped or attributed text.

And it appeared that the only accurate way is `sizeThatFits:`

```
label.text = @"...";
CGSize s = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

Comment: but how do I get label.frame.size.width? it's 0 because of AutoLayout. And I don't want to set it manually